Unable to find Incident Report for aborted launch of first Shuttle flight
There is an amazingly well writen report on the aborted launch of the first(?) shuttle because the computers did not sync up. I remember reading this report and it being fascinating and prescient about the field of computer science: as systems became more and more complex, it becomes impossible to mathematically proof that your program is correct and new ways of testing are needed.
However, I seem unable to find the report. The best I could find was a New York Times articel referencing the abort

The space agency said tonight that it had identified the problem that had caused the computers aboard the space shuttle Columbia to refuse to ''talk to each other'' properly this morning. The computers balked just before the Columbia's scheduled launching, causing at least a two-day postponement of the spaceship's shakedown cruise.

Would anyone be able to help me find this report?
Thanks

There are several writeups on this. Perhaps you are thinking of the famous "Bug Heard Round the World" article.
Here is the introduction.

On April 10, 1981, about 20 minutes prior to the scheduled
launching of the first flight of America's Space Transportation
System, astronauts and technicians attempted to initialize the
software system which "backs-up" the quad - redundant primary
software system ...... and could not.
In fact, there was no
possible way, it turns out, that the BFS (Backup Flight Control
System) in the fifth onboard computer could have been initialized properly with the PASS (Primary Avionics Software System) already
executing in the other four computers.
There was a "bug" - a
very small, very improbable, very intricate, and very old mistake
in the initialization logic of the PASS.
It was the type of
mistake that gives programmers and managers alike nightmares -
and theoreticians and analysts endless challenge.
It was the
kind of mistake that "cannot happen" if one "follows all the
rules" of good software design and implementation.
It was the
kind of mistake that can never be ruled out in the world of real
systems development: a world involving hundreds of programmers
and analysts, thousands of hours of testing and simulation, and
millions of pages of design specifications, implementation
schedules, and test plans and reports.
Because in that world,
software is in fact "soft" - in a large complex real time control
system like the Shuttle's avionics system, software is pervasive
and, in virtually every case, the last subsystem to stabilize.
Software by its nature is the easiest place to correct problems -
but by that very nature, it becomes a tyrant to its users ard a
tenuous and murky unknown to the analysts.
Software is the
easiest to change .... but in change, it is the easiest to
compromise.


If this isn't the one you are looking for, please comment, and I'll add other possibilities.

That was the one! It wasn't a NASA report, I was searching for the wrong thing. Thank you very much!
